# Send data from c++ program to php web server

Tags: php, c++, linux, bash, sockets

I have a php script running in a web server in order to perform some inserts into a database. This script receives some encrypted data, decrypts it and push it into the db.

The responsible to send this data is a C++ program (Running in Linux), this program will send a message of no more than 40 characters every 5 seconds.

I was thinking on call some bash script that opens the URL (http://myserver.com/myscript.php?message=adfafdadfasfasdfasdf) and receives the message by argument.

I dont want a complex solution, because I just need to open the URL, it is a unidirectional communication channel.

Some simple solution to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable given the constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more robust solution would be to use `libcurl`, which lets you [open a http connection in a few lines](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html). Here's the self contained example from the link:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need to parse the result of the HTTP query, you could just use [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to call a standard utility like [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).

```
int retVal = system("wget -O- -q http://whatever.com/foo/bar");
// handle return value as per the system man page
```

This is basically the same as what you were thinking about, save the script indirection.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!! Finally I decided to use libcurl, very easy to use for my purposes :D